# Left adjoint to a a functor

Tags: category-theory

Let $\delta:Set\to Cat$ be a functor that sends a set to a discrete category whose objects are elements of the set. I see that the right adjoint is the object functor. However, I am struggling to define a left adjoint. I want some hints on how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The left adjoint to $\delta$ is the "connected components" functor.

Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, we can define an equivalence relation on $\text{ob}(\mathcal{C})$ by taking the symmetric and transitive closure of the relation $xRy$ $\Leftrightarrow$ there is an arrow $X\to Y$. An equivalence class for this relation is called a connected component of $\mathcal{C}$.

Now if $X$ is a set, then a functor $F\colon \mathcal{C}\to \delta(X)$ is completely determined by its action on objects (since $\delta(X)$ has at most one arrow between any two objects), and if $xRy$ in $\mathcal{C}$, then $F(x) = F(y)$ (since there are no arrows in $\delta(X)$ between distinct objects). It follows that $F$ sends every object in a connected component to the same object of $\delta(X)$, so the functors $\mathcal{C}\to \delta(X)$ are in natural bijection with the functions from the connected components of $\mathcal{C}$ to $X$.

Comment: Let $F:\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ be a functor. Then what does the connected components functor do to this functor?

Comment: If $X\subseteq \text{ob}(\mathcal{C})$ is a connected component of $\mathcal{C}$, then the image of $X$ under $F$ is contained in a connected component $Y$ of $\mathcal{D}$. The connected components functor maps $X$ to $Y$.